# Loading one view from nib in cocoa

Tags: xcode, cocoa, xib, nib

I would like to know, how to make Cocoa OS X application to show only one window, when NIB file contains more than one? I know it is possible (I saw a project where it was done this way) but always when I add secondary window to XIB, it opens automatically with the main one. The new window is not connected in any way with the main window nor "File's Owner", so I have no idea why Cocoa decides to display it.

It happens even in fresh application created by Xcode, so I suppose I need to do some additional step to avoid showing this second window automatically.

I am using Xcode 4.6 and still a newbie in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the window, select the Attributes tab in the far right pane, and uncheck **Visible At Launch**.

[image: Xcode Attributes Tab]